# Spring cloud, config server can not start, how to config uri for git

Tags: git, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am pretty interested in spring cloud project and now I am testing it, but blocked immediately.

1. In POM: I added this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2. For main application:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigServer
public class SpringConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

So based on the documentation, I just need to add `enableConfigServer`, then I tried to start it, this is the error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'environmentRepository' defined in class org.springframework.cloud.config.server.ConfigServerConfiguration$GitRepositoryConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to configure a uri for the git repository

So, how can I config a uri for git repository? There is nothing mentioned in the documentation.

Thanks for more clarification

Comment: You can mention it in application.yml as spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri. Even I am trying to get a hold on this subject, This resource helped me a lot, You should try it out as well [Spring-Cloud Sample]http://qiita.com/making@github/items/704d8e254e03c5cce546#what-is-spring-cloud-config

Answer (score 13):

Our example is [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/configserver).  The [configuration](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/configserver/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml#L23-L28) from `application.yml` looks like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo
```

Comment: Thanks for this info. but I have one issue, that its only fetch master branch from repository not the development or other based on the profiles. How can we specify profile specific git uri and branch ?

Comment: Ok I got it. Its basically **label** which I had to set under `uri` and since config server already open resource such as `/{label}/{name}-{profiles}.yml` by default label goes to master as per doc.

Comment: @spencergibb so for adding encryption/decryption mechanism I added keystore [*.jsk] in the classpath but couldnot start the application due to unsatisfied dependency. I added rsa dependency but still seeing the same error. could you comment or should I take it as a new question?

Comment: Any quick help here - Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.RefNotFoundException: Ref master cannot be resolved?

Comment: see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1722#issuecomment-832193347

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and it was resolved when I set the profile in application.yml file as below:

```
spring:  
 profiles:   
  active: native
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this solves issue

in yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/user/microservices-central-config-repourl.git
          clone-on-start: true
          default-label: main
```

OR

in property file

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main
```

Answer (score -4):

About this serious problem, all you need to do is clean your maven repository and update it one again. That's worked for me !!

Comment: Please, enhance your answer by adding more info about solution to the question